# Android - some code executes after the phone went to a different Activity

Tags: android

I have a strange scenario here.

I have this code:

```
// For checking if the person is logged in.
first_time_check();

setContentView(R.layout.main);

// ...next lines of code
```

and the first_time_check() function checks if the user is logged in for the first time.  If their user_id is not in the SharedPreferences, I redirect them to log in:

```
public void first_time_check()
{   
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( ProblemioActivity.this);

    String user_id = prefs.getString( "user_id", null ); // First arg is name and second is if not found.
    String first_time_cookie = prefs.getString( "first_time_cookie" , null );               

    // About setting cookie.  Check for first time cookie
    if ( first_time_cookie == null )
    {
        // This user is a first-time visitor, 1) Create a cookie for them
        first_time_cookie = "1";

        // 2) Set it in the application session.
        prefs.edit().putString("first_time_cookie", first_time_cookie ).commit(); 

        // Make a remote call to the database to increment downloads number
        // AND send me an email that it was a new user.                 
    }        
    else
    {
        // If not first time, get their id.
        // If user_id is empty, make them an account.  
        // If id not empty, call the update login date and be done.         

        if ( user_id == null )
        {
            // User id is null so they must have logged out.                                
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProblemioActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            ProblemioActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else
        {               
            // Make a remote call to the database to increment downloads number                                 
        }
    }

return;
}
```

So after the code executes the

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProblemioActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            ProblemioActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

it still executes below the original code that calls this functions.

Any idea how that can happen?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this code all in onCreate? I'm not sure... but I would guess that onCreate will finish executing no matter what.

Comment: The call to the first_time_check function is in onCreate

Comment: Interesting point about the onCreate finishing execution no matter what - I didn't realize that....although not sure if that effects what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is excerpted from the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

> ```
> Shutting Down an Activity
> You can shut down an activity by calling its finish() method.
> You can also shut down a separate activity that you previously
> started by calling finishActivity().
>
> Note: In most cases, you should not explicitly finish an activity
> using these methods. As discussed in the following section about the
> activity lifecycle, the Android system manages the life of an
> activity for you, so you do not need to finish your own activities.
> Calling these methods could adversely affect the expected user
> experience and should only be used when you absolutely do not want
> the user to return to this instance of the activity.
> ```

Calling finish() on the activity seems appropriate here as you do not want the user to return to this activity.

Comment: that is interesting about the activity. Thanks for digging that up.